# How can I measure the transmission time between two android devices?

Tags: android, network-programming, wifi-direct

I would like to monitor Wifi-Direct network (Bandwidth, latency etc). How can I measure the time it takes for X bytes to be received over a network (wifi direct). I mean **TX + over the network + RX** time.

In DMMS (android Studio)I found the option of Network Statistics but here it is only shown transmission and reception time (and it is not very accurate because it appears on a graph).

I had thought about using System.currentTimeMillis() but I have not found how to synchronize the clocks of both devices.

TX:

```
                socket.bind(null);
                socket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(host, port)), SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
                int tamMensaje= 1024*1024; // 1 MB
                byte[] bitAleatorio = new byte [tamMensaje]; // 1 byte [-128 a 127
                for (int x=0;x<bitAleatorio.length;x++){
                    bitAleatorio[x] =(byte) Math.round(Math.random());
                }

                DataOutputStream DOS = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                for(int i=0;i<1024;i++){
                    DOS.write(bitAleatorio,(i*1024),1024);
                          }
```

RX:

```
                            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                            DataInputStream DIS = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());

                            int tamMensaje= 1024*1024;
                            byte[] msg_received2= new byte [tamMensaje];
                        for(int i=0;i<1024;i++){
                            DIS.read(msg_received2,(i*1024),1024);
                        }
                            client.close();
                            serverSocket.close();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches that can considerably accurate solve the problem:

1. **Sync time on both devices**.

You can use NTP for that and either install a [separate app like this one](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/set-your-android-atomic-time-for-perfectly-synced-clock-0170500/) or implement it in your code using a library [like this one](https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android).

After that you can rely on `System.currentTimeMillis()` to compare the message sent/receive time on both devices.

2. **Using relative time or time of single device**.

You can implement something like `icmp` echo, using udp datagrams (they are faster than tcp). The algorithm should be following (assuming we have devices A and B):

1. A sends some packet to B and saves `timeSent` somewhere;
2. B receives packet and immediately sends `ACK` packet to A;
3. A receives `ACK` and saves `timeRecv`;
4. Finally, `Long latency = (timeSent - timeRecv)/2;`.

This will work for small payloads, like `icmp` echo. Measuring large network transmission time can be done by sending separate `ACK` responses for both start/end of receiving it.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer.

1. As i´m using Wifi direct, it's probably that i don´t have internet access, so i don´t know if it´s possible that one mobile works as a NTP server and the other one syncs by this wifi direct connection(it´s doesn't matter if the hour is correct, i only want that both devices have the same time for the measures).

2. I want to check it in vehicular environment (in movement), so i think that if i have to divide the time in two it´s no exacty correct. In this case i suppose that it´s better if i use  the same quantity of information (tx=ack) isn´t it?

Comment: Dani, 1. You can use NTP in WiFi Direct scenario as well, either if one of your devices will act as Internet gateway or it will act as an NTP server.  I don't know does it really worth to mess with. 

2. It is correct to say that this approach won't give you exact latency value, but it seems to be the most accurate among the simplest solutions. Yes, dividing by 2 will be relatively accurate for small payloads of the exact or very close size.

Comment: Thanks. I have another doubt about the buffer size, I use "getSendBufferSize()" and "getReceiveBufferSize()" to know buffer size. It changes at the beginning but finally it always have similar values when i send a big array (buffer size:76384,1220608 for example). I don´t know if there are some default values for the buffer size or if it´s better to stablish a static value.

On the other hand,when I´m going to send my 10MB i have to split my array in smaller pieces, because in other case it doesn´t work properly (Not send all the bytes), and i don´t know why. What is the better size?